# Writing a function that depends on previous values of itself

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have created the following function

```
numberstocks <- function (x)
sapply (seq_along(x), function(i) {
    for (i in 1) {
    ifelse (x[i]==0,0,ifelse(x[i]==-1,100,ifelse(x[i]==1,0,0)))
    }
    for (i in 2:10){
    ifelse (x[i]==0, ifelse(is.numeric(numberstocks(x[i-1]))>-1,numberstocks(x[i-1]),0),ifelse(x[i]==0,0,ifelse(x[i]==-1,100,ifelse(x[i]==1,-1*is.numeric(numberstocks(x[i-1])),0))))
}
})
```

My data looks something like this:

```
AAPL <- c(1,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,0,-1)
MSFT <- c(0,0,0,1,0,-1,0,1,-1,0)

df <- data.frame (AAPL,MSFT)
```

And I want to apply the function to my data frame

```
df.new <- as.data.frame (lapply(df,numberstocks))
```

The desired output would be:

```
AAPL.new <- (100,100,100,-100,0,100,100,100,100,-100)
MSFT.new <- (0,0,0,100,100,-100,0,100,-100,0)
```

However, it says "data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows" and I do not understand why. Could someone identify what I am doing wrong?

I am a begginer moving from small sample sizes in Excel to larger sample sizes in R.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I can't be sure without a reproducible example but I suspect you should use if and else instead of ifelse.

Comment: I don't understand the code, your using sapply with a function of `i` but then using a for loop also with `i`.. Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @Roland, sorry if it was not clear. I have added a reproducible example and the respective error

Comment: @Vandenman, sorry if it was not clear. I have added a reproducible example. As I have mentioned in the post, I am a begginer. Hence, the function can be wrong due to using sapply and the loop. How can I overcome that?

Comment: No worries, the beginning is always difficult. However, I still don't understand what the desired output is. Could you provide that as well?

Comment: @Vandenman I have now added the desired output

Comment: Can you also give us the rules (in plain english) to follow in order to get the desired output? I have already found some errors in your code so it's difficult to see from the input how to get to `df.new`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas it is easier if I explain what I am trying to do. Basically, the "1" means that I buy the stock and the "-1" means that I sell it. And 0 means that there is no movement. What I want with "numberstocks" is to see how many stocks I hold at each point in time. And for simplicity purposes I am assuming that I can only have 100 stocks. Hence, for example for AAPL, I buy in the first period and hold it until the fourth period where I sell it. Hence during the first 3 periods I have it in my portfolio (thus the 100) and in the fourth, I sell it (thus the -100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below a function that matches for your input/ output. Basically, it, loops through every value of the array and derives the new value from the input.

```
AAPL <- c(1,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,0,-1)
AAPL.new <- c(100,100,100,-100,0,100,100,100,100,-100)

foo <- function(x) {

    newValue <- 0

    for (i in 1:length(x)) {

        if (x[i] == -1) {
            newValue <- -100
        } else if (x[i] == 1) {
            newValue <- 100
        } else if (x[i] == 0 && newValue != 100) {
            newValue <- 0
        }

        x[i] <- newValue

    }

    return(x)

}

# check whether the results match
foo(AAPL) == AAPL.new

AAPL <- c(1,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,0,-1)
MSFT <- c(0,0,0,1,0,-1,0,1,-1,0)
df <- data.frame (AAPL,MSFT)

# now use sapply to execute the function on every column
sapply(df, foo) 

MSFT.new <- c(0,0,0,100,100,-100,0,100,-100,0)
df.new <- data.frame(AAPL.new, MSFT.new)

# check whether the results match
as.data.frame(sapply(df, foo)) == df.new
```